# Comparing a string not working

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe

I have

Bascially how it is suppose to work is when you press enter a random int is suppose to be generated, you're suppose to match it in the second textfield. Press enter and then it will print out it's as soon as I have tried to do the equals part something has gone wrong and I'm not sure where, any help would appreciated :)

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: "...something has gone wrong" What is happening instead?

Comment: if I match the string correctly it prints nothing, then if I go to press enter again to generate a new one that won't work either.

Answer (score 4):

There's no opportunity to match it. You generate a random string, then you compare it to the other text field. There's no point in time for you to type in what you see.

After the key handler runs, if you *then* type in the random string you see and press enter, it'll generate the next random string before comparing your input to the previous one.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you need, but I'd guess you should move the `RandomString` stuff after the `if (....equals(...))` statement. edit: ... and also after the part where you set the text to `""` for both.